Question on Stability and Boundedness in Nonlinear Systems
I have a question regarding the analysis of two nonlinear autonomous systems as described below:

Suppose we have two systems:
$$
\dot{x} = f_1(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \dot{x} = f_2(x),
$$
where the conditions for existence and uniqueness of solutions are satisfied for both.

It is known that the system $\dot{x} = f_1(x)$ is stable in the sense of Lyapunov. Additionally, there exists a positive definite function $V(\cdot)$ such that:
$$
 V(\varphi_2(t, x_0)) \leq V(\varphi_1(t, x_0)),
$$
where $\varphi_1(t, x_0)$ and $\varphi_2(t, x_0)$ are the trajectories of the systems $\dot{x} = f_1(x)$ and $\dot{x} = f_2(x),$ respectively.

Let $W$ be a continuous function such that $W(0) = 0.$ Furthermore, suppose the integral of $\max\{W, 0\}$ along the trajectories of the system $\dot{x} = f_1(x)$ over $[0, \infty)$ is bounded and continuously dependent on the initial condition $x_0.$


My Question
The goal is to prove that the integral of $W$ along the trajectories of the system $\dot{x} = f_2(x)$ over $[0, \infty)$ is also bounded.
To achieve this, I need to establish the existence of a bounded, positive variable $k$ such that:
$$
 W(\varphi_2(t, x_0)) \leq k \cdot W(\varphi_1(t, x_0)) \quad \forall t, x_0.
$$
$\quad$ 1. Do you think this statement is true or false?
$\quad$ 2. If true, could you provide a hint or direction on how to prove it?
$\quad$ 3. If false, what additional conditions might ensure its validity?

You will at least need more assumptions on $W$ for this question to be meaningful, because as stated, $W(\sigma)=0$ (the constant zero function) satisfies all your conditions and thus makes your statement (trivially) true.
